# In Nix, how to make one derivation depend on another next to it?

Tags: packaging, binary, nix

I'm currently trying to package some closed-source software into Nix derivations. The app is distributed as a large pile of `.deb` files, and most of them contain libraries that the other parts of the app can use.

To simplify, assume that `app.deb` contains the actual application, and `lib.deb` contains a library that the app requires.

Currently I have:

```
# default.nix
let
  nixpkgs = fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tarball/nixos-23.11";
  pkgs = import nixpkgs {
    config = { };
    overlays = [ ];
  };
in {
  lib = pkgs.callPackage ./lib.nix { };
  app = pkgs.callPackage ./app.nix { };
}
```

```
# lib.nix
{ lib, stdenv, autoPatchelfHook, dpkg, requireFile,
libcxx, libgcc, }:

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  pname = "myapp-lib";
  version = "1.0.0";
  src = requireFile {
    name = "lib.deb";
    sha256 = "313e8686118ccba397de0bdfca101f1053b758227fd9d3510ea78644f2450bfe";
    url = "https://softwarecorp.example/downloads";
  };

  nativeBuildInputs = [
    dpkg
    autoPatchelfHook
  ];

  unpackPhase = "dpkg-deb -x $src .";

  buildInputs = [ libcxx libgcc ];

  installPhase = ''
    cp -r lib $out/
  '';
}
```

```
# app.nix
{ lib, stdenv, autoPatchelfHook, dpkg, requireFile,
libcxx, }:

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  pname = "myapp-bin";
  version = "1.0.0";
  src = requireFile {
    name = "app.deb";
    sha256 = "f4abbdb3f83d982569c5cd30ce5ad63ec4e49011d165e17a2c59d9a613f163b9";
    url = "https://softwarecorp.example/downloads";
  };

  nativeBuildInputs = [
    dpkg
    autoPatchelfHook
  ];

  unpackPhase = "dpkg-deb -x $src .";

  buildInputs = [ libcxx ];

  installPhase = ''
    cp -r bin $out/
  '';

  runtimeDependencies = [ myapp-lib ];  # <-- how to do this?
}
```

The `lib` derivation builds on its own, and now I want to add the things it contains to the `app` derivation.
I can't just add it to the regular list of package dependencies at the top of the file.
I'd also like to avoid submitting the package to nixpkgs at this time, because I'm not sure I'll be able to package the app fully, and I don't want to become its maintainer before I know it can be done.

Alternatively, are there any good patterns for packaging closed-source software like this that would avoid needing to make lots of derivations? From what I can tell, the libraries here all have the same version, and are never used anywhere else in the company's products, so building a single derivation could be acceptable here.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid making two derivation could simply not package the library and simply import it before the `installPhase`. This could be done by extracting the library files in `postUnpack`:

```
# app.nix
{
  stdenv,
  autoPatchelfHook,
  dpkg,
  requireFile,
  libcxx,
}: let
  myLib = requireFile {
    name = "lib.deb";
    sha256 = "313e8686118ccba397de0bdfca101f1053b758227fd9d3510ea78644f2450bfe";
    url = "https://softwarecorp.example/downloads";
  };
in
  stdenv.mkDerivation {
    pname = "myapp-bin";
    version = "1.0.0";
    src = requireFile {
      name = "app.deb";
      sha256 = "f4abbdb3f83d982569c5cd30ce5ad63ec4e49011d165e17a2c59d9a613f163b9";
      url = "https://softwarecorp.example/downloads";
    };

    nativeBuildInputs = [
      dpkg
      autoPatchelfHook
    ];

    unpackPhase = "dpkg-deb -x $src .";

    postUnpack = ''
      dpkg-deb -x ${myLib} .
      cp -r lib $out/
    '';

    buildInputs = [libcxx];

    installPhase = ''
      cp -r bin $out/
    '';
  }
```

The package [`epson-alc1100`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/1bfeb2ddc637ea3164066246d64664052eaeacc6/pkgs/misc/drivers/epson-alc1100/default.nix) is an example of this kind of implementation.

Comment: And if I need to extend this to many other libraries, then I'd add multiple instances of the `myLib` declaration and more `dpkg-deb -x` lines into the `postUnpack` section?

Comment: Yes exactly, just beware of potential conflicts when extracting multiple libraries with `dpkg -x`.

Comment: Well, the original software intends that you just install every `.deb` file in sequence, so I assume that's not going to be an issue.

Comment: It should not be since usually each library file have a different name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to be able to access the `lib` derivation while you are writing the expression for `app`.  So you should change the bottom of `default.nix` to have a "recursive" set where the elements can refer to each other, and pass `lib` as an argument to `app`:

```
{
  lib = pkgs.callPackage ./lib.nix { };
  app = pkgs.callPackage ./app.nix { inherit lib; };
}
```

Now `app.nix` needs to have an argument named `lib`, but it looks like you already added that.  (Actually, in your real code I hope the argument is named something else, because `pkgs.lib` is a library provided by `nixpkgs`, and you want to be able to use that in your derivation without a name conflict.)

Now in `app.nix`, just write `inherit lib;` in your set that you are passing to `mkDerivation`.  This is equivalent to `lib = lib;`, and that means it will set an environment variable named `lib` equal to the output path of the `lib` derivation.  (Despite what you wrote in your question, I don't think `runtimeDependencies` is a valid argument to `mkDerivation`.)

Now in your builder script for `app` you can do whatever is needed to make `lib` be a runtime dependency of `app`.  For example, you might write `ln -s $out/lib $lib` to make a symbolic link.  The exact details of what you are going to do here depends on the details of how the app finds its libraries, and I don't have those details so I can only tell your generalities.

Run `nix-build -A app` and look in the `result` symlink in your current directory to see what you built, and make sure it refers to `lib` in the way you are expecting.

Comment: Like I asked the other answer, how do you extend this to many derivations being used? Just copy the line into `lib2 = ...` and `inherit lib2;`?

Comment: Yeah, for each derivation that depends on libraries defined in the same set, just write `inherit lib1 lib2 lib3;`.  There is probably some fancy Nix way to make `callPackage` work for your project and save you a little bit of typing, but writing out the dependencies explicitly will help you understand the structure of your system better.